# How to remove list name from search result in sharepoint foundation 2010?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

My search result page is showing list items along with list name.But i dont want list name in search result.
Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**SharePoint Server (or Search Server Express)**
If running SharePoint Server (or Search Server Express) you can change the XSLT used to display the search results:

1. Go to the search result page
2. Put it in Edit mode
3. On the Search Core Result Web part select "Edit Web Part"
4. Open the Display Properties category
5. Deselect "Use Location Visualization"
6. Click XSL Editor
7. Remove the following section:

.

```
<span class="srch-URL2" id="{concat($currentId,'_Url')}">  
  <xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:when test="hithighlightedproperties/HHUrl[. != '']">  
       <xsl:call-template name="HitHighlighting">  
          <xsl:with-param name="hh" select="hithighlightedproperties/HHUrl" />   
       </xsl:call-template>   
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:otherwise>  
       <xsl:value-of select="url"/>  
    </xsl:otherwise>   
  </xsl:choose>
</span>
```

**SharePoint Foundation**
If you're running pure SharePoint Foundation, I recommend that you "upgrade" to Search Server Express if you want to use Search for anything except the most simple search on the current site.

If you stay with the pure Foundation, then you have no way of changing the XSLT, then your only option is to add css to remove the URL.

```
.srch-URL2 {
  display:none;
}
```

This can be inserted into the master page or in a Css file which is the set as AlternateCSS which can be done in PowerShell like this:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://spf-dev
$w.AlternateCssUrl = 'http://spf-dev/Style%20Library/MyCss.css'
$w.Update()
```

This needs to be done on all Sites where you need it :-(